# How can I join 2 tables together, and then count by 2 columns?

Tags: mysql, join, count

Say I have these 2 tables:

[image: tables]

What is the best way for me to join these 2 tables, and then count the number of userids per country, per category?

Answer (score 2):

You could try the below query, I don't have mySQL, but it is standard SQL that should do the work.

```
SELECT country, category, count(1) FROM users u 
   JOIN submissions s ON u.userid= s.userid GROUP BY country, category
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following (all of the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=def90a8a55c2cf25ad1e055a3f50dec8)):

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
  user_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  u_date  DATE NOT NULL,
  country VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL
);
```

Populate it (some extra records for demonstration purposes):

```
INSERT INTO users VALUES
(123, '2022-12-01', 'USA'),
(124, '2022-12-01', 'Ireland'),
(125, '2022-12-01', 'Japan');
```

Note the use of the ISO 8601 date format (i.e. YYYY-MM-DD) - this is a standard and most database systems accept dates in this format.

And:

```
CREATE TABLE submissions
(
  submission_id   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id         INTEGER NOT NULL,
  submission_date DATE,
  category        VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT sub_user_fk FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id)
);
```

And again with some extra records:

```
INSERT INTO submissions VALUES
(1, 123, '2022-12-02', 'business'),
(2, 123, '2022-12-02', 'business'),
(3, 123, '2022-12-02', 'tourism'),
(4, 123, '2022-12-02', 'tourism'),
(5, 123, '2022-12-02', 'tourism'),
(6, 124, '2022-12-02', 'business'),
(7, 124, '2022-12-02', 'tourism');

--
-- Note: no records in submissions for user 125
--
```

And then we run:

```
SELECT 
  u.user_id, u.country, s.category, 
  COUNT(s.category) AS cat_cnt
FROM
  users u
INNER JOIN
  submissions s
  ON u.user_id = s.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_id, u.country, s.category
ORDER BY u.user_id, u.country;
```

Result:

```
user_id  country    category    cat_cnt
123          USA    tourism           3
123          USA    business          2
124      Ireland    tourism           1
124      Ireland    business          1
```

Note that the `JOIN` here is an `INNER` join - which is the default if not specified. However, we might well wish to know who's **not** made any submissions (or purchases or whatever you're interested in).

We do this by way of a `LEFT JOIN` which will include **all** of the records from the left hand side of the join with NULLs for those records on the right hand side with no corresponding entries - in this case, the user from Japan has no submissions so will not appear in the first report but does appear in the second as follows:

```
SELECT 
  u.user_id, u.country, COALESCE(s.category, '------'), 
  COUNT(s.category) AS cat_cnt
FROM
  users u
LEFT JOIN
  submissions s
  ON u.user_id = s.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_id, u.country, s.category
ORDER BY u.user_id, u.country;
```

Result:

```
user_id  country    coalesce    cat_cnt
123          USA     tourism          3
123          USA    business          2
124      Ireland     tourism          1
124      Ireland    business          1
125        Japan     ------           0
```

We use the [`COALESCE()`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-coalesce/) function to input a string to replace `NULL` - just a presentation thing - you may wish to let your application's presentation layer take care of that!

As mentioned in my comment, please **always** include your version of MySQL! Also, when asking questions like this in future, please include a fiddle with your table definitions and some sample data so that a) we have a single source of truth for the question and that b) there is no duplication of effort on behalf of those trying to answer - help us to help you!

### Edit:

As pointed out by @AnandSowmithiran, I included a bit too much detail in my original answer - I've left the original unchanged, but as he points out, the exact answer to your question is more properly formulated as follows (new fiddle added [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=6f5f2120d18ee4d15647277fc66abb47)):

First, we can add some records to the `users` and `submissions` tables:

```
INSERT INTO users VALUES
(126, '2022-12-01', 'USA');
```

And:

```
INSERT INTO submissions VALUES
( 8, 126, '2022-12-02',  'tourism'),
( 9, 126, '2022-12-02',  'tourism'),
(10, 126, '2022-12-02',  'tourism'),
(11, 126, '2022-12-02', 'business'),
(12, 126, '2022-12-02', 'business');
```

and then:

```
SELECT 
  u.country, COALESCE(s.category, '------') AS category, 
  COUNT(s.category) AS cat_cnt
FROM
  users u
LEFT JOIN
  submissions s
  ON u.user_id = s.user_id
GROUP BY u.country, s.category
ORDER BY u.country, category DESC, s.category;
```

Result:

```
country     category    cat_cnt
Ireland      tourism          1
Ireland     business          1
Japan        ------           0
USA          tourism          6
USA         business          4
```

i.e. you don't want a breakdown by `user_id`, just by `country` and `category`. Inspection shows that this is the correct result.